# Linq to SQL and Entity Framework in Same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a project that is using l2s. We are going to expand with new modules. Now we are thinking of using entity framework for new modules as it is not possible for us to change our existing modules to EF. Can some one share experiences of using both l2s and EF in same mvc project

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There wont be any problem in using both of them in same project. Both have their own way to access data and will not conflict with each other. But I would suggest you to slowly migrate your data access to either one of these technology as having two data access methods in same project may lead to maintenance issue

Comment: Could u please highlight some maintenance issue

Comment: It is often stated that there should be only one way to do things in a system i.e one functionality should be handled by only one component as that allows you to easily implement new features on top of this component and extend its functionality also fixing bugs will be only at one place along with avoiding code duplication as you have only one place to put your new functionality. These data access abstract your data store of application and it is not good to have 2 abstraction in a system that are abstracting the same underlying resource.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned - no issues with having them both - but having two technologies is 
1. More difficult to follow
2. You sometimes need to maintain separate pieces of connection info
3. You require multiple skillsets 
4. If l2s is ever deprecated - then you really should switch to one. True - its not currently deprecated as some thought it would be but its a better practice to be *consistent* inside of any one project.

Comment: i agree and certainly we will move to one technique but this time wit may not be possible to change the existing code